# Can I improve Sqlite Connection.Open time?

Tags: performance, sqlite

We are using SQLite databases for a WPF app running on Windows.  General performance is great.  One area we would like to improve is application launch.  We need to load and retrieve information from 2 different databases on the file system before the application is usable.  The call to Connection.Open takes about 2 seconds the first time it is called on each database.  By making the calls in parallel, I have been able to shorten overall load time, but the database load still represents 40% of our startup time. All subsequent calls to those databases are very fast.

From what I can tell, the call to Open has a lot of checks for configuration, etc.  Is there some way to optimize all of that when setting up the database so it doesn't have to be done each time the Open method is called?  Or is there any other way to improve the performance of the initial call to Open?

Comment: `The call to Connection.Open takes about 2 seconds the first time` that's extreme. SQLite is an embedded database - it's your own application that opens it, manages connections and executes queries. You'll have to find out what's wrong. Does the application leave garbage that need to be cleaned up each time the database starts again perhaps?

Comment: Are you using a Write-Ahead Log that has a lot of operations that weren't committed? SQLite is a single-user database and doesn't allow multiple connections unless you enable WAL. Even then, only a single thread applies the changes from the WAL to the data files. If you stop the app abruptly, next time you start SQLite will have to bring the database to a stable state according to the transaction log. You can avoid that by ensuring you close the databases properly

Comment: We are using WAL.  In my test that takes 2 seconds, nothing is pending.  How do I check for garbage that needs to be cleaned up or how do I force clean up?  I doubt there would be much clean up for this test as I am just opening, reading some records and then closing it again.